# Third and Triple

Tags: mathematics, logical-deduction

This is inspired from
[Half and Double Value](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/71661/half-and-double-value/71747#71747).
Please see that puzzle, too.

Okay, so now you're really bored.

A good puzzle wastes time, so you make one.

**Try to find the smallest number, that, when you rearrange the digits, it can triple or third.**

$update -$
*I meant the 2 NEW numbers are a third and triple of the original number.*

Bonus for anyone who does this with logic.

Comment: It takes @ngn 's program a lot longer to do this than half and double. (Not posting the answer because no logic was used and I literally just stole all his work)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand it correctly:

> $31046895$. When divided by three it becomes $10348965$ and when multiplied by three it becomes $93140685$.

As with the previous riddle that you linked, I wrote a lazy brute force in `C#` to solve it. It took roughly 45 seconds to perform all of the needed calculations. I could refactor this, but meh.

```
for (int i = 0; i < int.MaxValue; i++) {
    if (contains(i)) {
        WriteLine(i);
        break;
    }
}
WriteLine("Done");
ReadKey();

static bool contains(int i) {
    Dictionary<char, int> ivals = getVals(i);
    Dictionary<char, int> tdvals = getVals(i / 3);
    Dictionary<char, int> tpvals = getVals(i * 3);

    if (i.ToString().Length != (i / 3).ToString().Length ||
        i.ToString().Length != (i * 3).ToString().Length)
        return false;

    foreach (char c in ivals.Keys) {
        if (!tdvals.ContainsKey(c)) return false;
        else if (tdvals[c] != ivals[c]) return false;

        if (!tpvals.ContainsKey(c)) return false;
        else if (tpvals[c] != ivals[c]) return false;
    }

    WriteLine($"third {i / 3}");
WriteLine($"triple {i * 3}");
    return true;
}
static Dictionary<char, int> getVals(int i) {
    Dictionary<char, int> vals = new Dictionary<char, int>();
    foreach (char c in i.ToString()) {
        if (vals.ContainsKey(c))
            vals[c]++;
        else
            vals.Add(c, 1);
    }
    return vals;
}
```

Comment: How does rearranging the digits make 1 or 9? The only digit is 3.

Comment: 3 rearranged is 3. It's a technical answer, as I said; I'll be giving another answer in a bit as I am working on it lol

Comment: Okay, I see. [extra text]

Comment: @Alto I see that I didn't understand the requirements fully when I gave my initial answer; I've corrected.

Comment: You seem to grab a 9 out of nowhere for your triple.

Comment: That's what I was worried about; however, I found the answer that meets that requirement.

Comment: @Alto, I've corrected my answer.

Answer (score 1):

My answers are probably breaking the rules, but here goes.

My first answer

> 0. But, I'm assuming that you meant to specify 'positive' integer.

My second answer (I cheated by using fractions)

> 1 
>  
>  3 => (27 / 4) / (9 / 4) 
>  1 => (94 / 47) / 2 
>  1 / 3 => (9 / 4) / (27 / 4)

Comment: What? How did you see that?

Comment: Honestly I think I got lucky! I had the idea to try fractions but I was having difficulty with getting the triple, and then I tried those numbers and it actually worked.